# Str.lastIndexOf("\") giving an error

Tags: java, string

I want to remove last occurrence of  "\" this special character from my string. 
I tried it with string functions like

```
String word = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("\"));
```

But every time I am getting an error which is asking to put an extra quote.
 Meanwhile I found out ("\"") is used to pass " this special character. 
How do I proceed?

Comment: this \ is an escape character, so you need to escaped

Comment: Remember that `\ ` is the character to "escape character". So to use this character, you need to escape the escape character -> `\\ `

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use

```
String word = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("\\"));
```

the `\` character inside a string is escaping special characters (`",',\` and so forth). So using a `\` before them would make it *literal*, which means java treats what comes after it as if it's a regular character.

You can test to see what

```
System.out.println("\\");
```

would print. It would print `\`.

So:

```
System.out.println("\" "); //would print one like this: "
System.out.println("\' "); //would print one like this: '
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is an escape character. If you are using `"\"`, its like escaping `"` character. Java understands it as `" \" (quote missing)`. Hence the error to close the quote appears.

To resolve it you need to escape the `\` character.

```
String word = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("\\"));
```